# Why coudn't I connect to the server?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm using `g++ 4.9.2` compiler and wrote the following code to try my first example with sockets.

```
char *buf = new char[1000];
int iResult;

int main(){    
   WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    addrinfo hints, *result;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    std::cout << WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) << std::endl;
    iResult = getaddrinfo("173.194.40.231", "80", &hints, &result);
    std::cout << iResult;
    ConnectSocket = socket(result -> ai_family, result -> ai_socktype, result -> ai_protocol); //1, HERE
    connect(ConnectSocket, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
}
```

The issue, that I got `Segmentation fault` at `1`. Because of `getaddrinfo("173.194.40.231", "80", &hints, &result);` returned `11003`, therefore `&result` pointed to `NULL`. Why? I typed valid address and port.

It was `google.com` and we can open up it in browser. Couldn't someone help me out?

Comment: What does your debugger say? Where are your `#include`s? What output do you get before the segfault (if any)?

Comment: `The issue, that I got Segmentation fault at 1`  First thing you should do is never assume things will work.  You're supposed to test your return values instead of going on assuming things are ok.  You are also to call  `WSAGetLastError` when this occurs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My debugger said what I was wrote in the post. What else it could say?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit BTW, I tried to initialize addirnfo explicitly as `addrinfo hints = addrinfo();` and it worked. But I thought the declaration  `addrinfo hints` should cause default initialization (that's with `addrinfo()`). What's wrong?

Comment: @user3663882 - The `hints` variable is local.  Local variables do not have a default initial value unless you explicitly give it one.  So the parentheses default initializes the struct.

Comment: @user3663882: It tells you a stack trace, the values of variables, all sorts. Just "segmentation fault" is pretty much _zero information_.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That's not true. The default initialisation of members of aggregates with automatic storage duration is a no-op, sure. But you imply that every local variable is just not initialised, which is not true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - In the "give it one" in the comment, I meant to also include types with a user-defined default constructor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If `hints` is not default initialized so what value it have after the declaration `addrinfo hints`?

Comment: @user3663882: Unspecified value. From the look of `getaddrinfo` that shouldn't matter, as it's strictly an "out" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
```

getaddrinfo() tries to fill up with existing data provided. Garbage data is confusing the function.

Comment: This would also work:

`addrinfo hints = addrinfo();`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Why should we ever do that? Does `addrinfo hints;` declaration already cause default initializationn?

Comment: @user3663882 No, the declaration alone (without parentheses) doesn't do that -- you wind up with junk, just as the answer says.  Adding the parentheses default initializes the struct, which makes those members all 0.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, it does. Please read carefully the chapter 8.5/12 of the C++ Final Working Draft. I cite the crucial part: If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. What would you say? I'm confused....

Comment: @user3663882 Well how do you explain why your struct was junk-filled?   If local variables (leaving out ones with a user-defined default constructor) were automatically initialized to 0, then we would have no questions on SO concerning these issues.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153725/typedef-struct-default-initialization  and please see the answer with 12 upvotes here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782103/initializing-default-values-in-a-struct

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So, if the variable `hints` were a global variable it would be default initialized, am I right? But in the case of local variables the value is indeterminate.

Comment: @user3663882 Yes, if it were a global variable, then you would have default initialization.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Thank you very much. Why don't you provide your comments as an answer? I think it might be useful for someone else...